# android ExpandableListView animate drop down and up?

Tags: android, expandablelistview

Recently I meet a question is that how to let the `ExpandableListView` animate drop down and up. I search the result on StackOverflow.
There's an answer:[Android animate drop down/up view proper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9248930/android-animate-drop-down-up-view-proper)
But it fit to the `ListView`. When I use it on `ExpandableListView`, it doesn't work. I think there must be someone who can solve this similar problem. If you have free time, could you tell me the solution or give tips to the question.

Comment: i've thought of a possible solution, [**here**][1] .


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20884167/878126