# Android: Up/down animated sliding menu

Tags: android, animation, view, menu, sliding

I have tried several solutions but need help. The topics below are really useful but I think I'm doing something wrong. How to set layout height/settings for both? Let's say I have 2 LinearLayout for content and bottom menu.

Also I don't want the bottom menu disappeared after sliding. It should be constant there. I am using fragments for menu clicks/change views.

[Android: Expand/collapse animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4946295/android-expand-collapse-animation)

[Android animate drop down/up view proper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9248930/android-animate-drop-down-up-view-proper)

[image]

Comment: Something similar to this? https://github.com/umano/AndroidSlidingUpPanel

Comment: @Waza_Be Thanks a lot! You saved my mind :)) I was trying to do something like this for some days. I liked it very much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As my comment seemed to help, I will post the link as an answer: https://github.com/umano/AndroidSlidingUpPanel

The full code cannot be pasted in StackOverflow, but the whole library will help you to achieve what you need.

> The 2.2 version of the Umano Android app features a sexy sliding up
>   draggable panel for the currently playing article. This type of a
>   panel is a common pattern also used in the Google Music app and the
>   Rdio app. This is an open source implementation of this component that
>   you are free to take advantage of in your apps. Umano Team <3 Open
>   Source.

```
<com.sothree.slidinguppaneldemo.SlidingUpPanelLayout
    android:id="@+id/sliding_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Main Content"
        android:textSize="16sp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center|top"
        android:text="The Awesome Sliding Up Panel"
        android:textSize="16sp" />
</com.sothree.slidinguppaneldemo.SlidingUpPanelLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also try this custom view for ExpandablePanel found it somewhere when i needed to create something like this.

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.TypedArray;
import android.graphics.Point;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Display;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.Transformation;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

public class ExpandablePanel extends LinearLayout {

    private final int mHandleId;
    private final int mContentId;

    // Contains references to the handle and content views
    private View mHandle;
    private View mContent;

    // Does the panel start expanded?
    private boolean mExpanded = false;
    // The height of the content when collapsed
    private int mCollapsedHeight = 0;
    // The full expanded height of the content (calculated)
    private int mContentHeight = 0;
    // How long the expand animation takes
    private int mAnimationDuration = 0;
    int height;
    private Context context;
    // Listener that gets fired onExpand and onCollapse
    private OnExpandListener mListener;

    public ExpandablePanel(Context context) {
        this(context, null);
        this.context = context;

    }

    public void setSize(int size) {
        this.height = size;
    }

    /**
     * The constructor simply validates the arguments being passed in and sets
     * the global variables accordingly. Required attributes are 'handle' and
     * 'content'
     */
    public ExpandablePanel(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        mListener = new DefaultOnExpandListener();

        TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs,
                R.styleable.ExpandablePanel, 0, 0);

        // How high the content should be in "collapsed" state
        mCollapsedHeight = (int) a.getDimension(
                R.styleable.ExpandablePanel_collapsedHeight, 0.0f);

        // How long the animation should take
        mAnimationDuration = a.getInteger(
                R.styleable.ExpandablePanel_animationDuration, 500);

        int handleId = a.getResourceId(R.styleable.ExpandablePanel_handle, 0);

        if (handleId == 0) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                    "The handle attribute is required and must refer "
                            + "to a valid child.");
        }

        int contentId = a.getResourceId(R.styleable.ExpandablePanel_content, 0);
        if (contentId == 0) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                    "The content attribute is required and must "
                            + "refer to a valid child.");
        }

        mHandleId = handleId;
        mContentId = contentId;

        a.recycle();
    }

    // Some public setters for manipulating the
    // ExpandablePanel programmatically
    public void setOnExpandListener(OnExpandListener listener) {
        mListener = listener;
    }

    public void setCollapsedHeight(int collapsedHeight) {
        mCollapsedHeight = collapsedHeight;
    }

    public void setAnimationDuration(int animationDuration) {
        mAnimationDuration = animationDuration;
    }

    /**
     * This method gets called when the View is physically visible to the user
     */
    @Override
    protected void onFinishInflate() {
        super.onFinishInflate();

        mHandle = findViewById(mHandleId);
        if (mHandle == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                    "The handle attribute is must refer to an"
                            + " existing child.");
        }

        mContent = findViewById(mContentId);
        if (mContent == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                    "The content attribute must refer to an"
                            + " existing child.");
        }

        // This changes the height of the content such that it
        // starts off collapsed
        android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams lp = mContent.getLayoutParams();
        lp.height = mCollapsedHeight;
        mContent.setLayoutParams(lp);

        // Set the OnClickListener of the handle view
        mHandle.setOnClickListener(new PanelToggler());
    }

    /**
     * This is where the magic happens for measuring the actual (un-expanded)
     * height of the content. If the actual height is less than the
     * collapsedHeight, the handle will be hidden.
     */
    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        // First, measure how high content wants to be
        mContent.measure(widthMeasureSpec, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
        mContentHeight = mContent.getMeasuredHeight();



        Log.v("cHeight", mContentHeight + "");
        Log.v("cCollapseHeight", mCollapsedHeight + "");

        if (mContentHeight < mCollapsedHeight) {
            mHandle.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        } else {
            mHandle.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

        // Then let the usual thing happen
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
    }

    /**
     * This is the on click listener for the handle. It basically just creates a
     * new animation instance and fires animation.
     */
    private class PanelToggler implements OnClickListener {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Animation a;
            if (mExpanded) {
                a = new ExpandAnimation(mContentHeight, mCollapsedHeight);
                mListener.onCollapse(mHandle, mContent);
            } else {
                a = new ExpandAnimation(mCollapsedHeight, mContentHeight);
                mListener.onExpand(mHandle, mContent);
            }
            a.setDuration(mAnimationDuration);
            mContent.startAnimation(a);
            mExpanded = !mExpanded;
        }
    }

    /**
     * This is a private animation class that handles the expand/collapse
     * animations. It uses the animationDuration attribute for the length of
     * time it takes.
     */
    private class ExpandAnimation extends Animation {
        private final int mStartHeight;
        private final int mDeltaHeight;

        public ExpandAnimation(int startHeight, int endHeight) {
            mStartHeight = startHeight;
            mDeltaHeight = endHeight - startHeight;
        }

        @Override
        protected void applyTransformation(float interpolatedTime,
                Transformation t) {
            android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams lp = mContent.getLayoutParams();
            lp.height = (int) (mStartHeight + mDeltaHeight * interpolatedTime);
            mContent.setLayoutParams(lp);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean willChangeBounds() {
            return true;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Simple OnExpandListener interface
     */
    public interface OnExpandListener {
        public void onExpand(View handle, View content);

        public void onCollapse(View handle, View content);
    }

    private class DefaultOnExpandListener implements OnExpandListener {
        public void onCollapse(View handle, View content) {
        }

        public void onExpand(View handle, View content) {
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Vipul. Can you please share a example to use this?