# Android SlidingUpPanelLayout and slidinguppanel

Tags: android

I am having problem to incorporate the sliding menu and sliding up panel from
http://www.michenux.net/android-sliding-menu-part-22-690.html
[Android: Up/down animated sliding menu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17603957/android-up-down-animated-sliding-menu)
  (https://github.com/umano/AndroidSlidingUpPanel)
When it first launched, the bottom panel showed up ok, I did a click/touch on the
sliding up panel, it goes up alright to show the second screen.  Problem come when I click/touch
again on the second screen, it slided down but the screen overshoot to lower screen.
It doesn't goes back to the original location.
I have marked problem with "?????" and red color.
[image: First Launched]
[image: After sliding up and down]

Answer (score 1):

I discard the use of the sliding from left menu.  The Android's Navigation Drawer suggested by the slidinguppannel solved this problem.
http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html